# socket: multithreading doesn't work when client reads messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have a server, which can accept two socket connections. It creates a thread for each socket so that messages can be sent parallel.

Now I'm trying to code my client.

I create a class named `SocketThread` as a thread of socket. Here is the main code:

```
void SocketThread::ReadData()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (!finished)
    {
        while ((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(Data))) > 0)
        {
            std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        }
    }
}

std::thread SocketThread::run()
{
    return std::thread([=] { ReadData(); });
}
```

in the function `main`:

```
SocketThread s0("127.0.0.1", 10000);
SocketThread s1("127.0.0.1", 10000);
std::thread td0{sts[0].run()};
std::thread td1{sts[1].run()};
td0.join(); // stop here
td1.join();
// something else
```

When I execute the program, it will block at `td0.join();`, meaning that I can get the id of the thread `td0` on the console and I can NEVER get the other thread.

However, when I remove `(n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(Data))) > 0`, which means that now the client is just a simple thread, that it won't receive anything, things gonna be fine ---- I can get two ids of the two threads.

Why?

**EDIT**
It seems that I used `join` incorrectly.
What I need is that `main` doesn't execute `//something else` until the two threads get 1000 characters together.
What should I do?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question, but `read()` call is a blocking one by default.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal When I execute the client, the `main` will block at `td0.join()`. Why.

Comment: because `join()` is blocking. `join()` returns when the thread ends. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: your thread hasn't completed yet. `join()` will return when your thread will finish its execution. If that's all your code, I suspect `read()` hasn't returned yet?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal What I need is that two threads execute parallel. The two threads execute parallel until they receive 1000 characters. So I shouldn't use `join`?

Comment: @shrike What I need is that two threads execute parallel. The two threads execute parallel until they receive 1000 characters.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I used `join` because `main` shouldn't execute until the two threads get 1000 characters. If I used `join` incorrectly, what should I do?

Comment: Listen, your when you fire off a thread - it's starts running whatever code it contains. It's still running somewhere else while your main code and other threads are running, all in parallel. But when you call `join()` in main, the execution of `main()` blocks till that thread hasn't completed it's execution. Now there's two possiblities here, either your thread has completed it's execution, or it hasn't. In the first case, `join()` will return instantly and continue the next execution statement, but in the later case, it'll be blocked till the thread returns. contd...

Comment: ... This doesn't means that other threads have stopped too. The only thread that stopped was who called `join()`. Other threads and the thread whose `join()` has been called are still executing in parallel.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Thanks. I think I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use `join()` incorrectly. If you want `main()` to block until both threads end, your code is correct : `td0.join()` will block until thread `td0` ends, and the same for `td1`.

Now, if you want your threads to end after receiving `sizeof(Data)` bytes, your function `void SocketThread::ReadData()` should rather look like this :

```
void SocketThread::ReadData()
{
    int n, total = 0;
    while (!finished)
    {
        while ((n = read(sockfd, &recvBuff[total], sizeof(Data) - total)) > 0)
        {
            total += n;
        }
        if (n == -1)
        {
            // manage error here
        }
        if (n == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "client shut the socket down; got " << total << " bytes over " << sizeof(Data) << std::endl;
            finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

For a short explanation : there is no guarantee that you can get all data sent by client in a single `read()` operation, so you need to call `read()` and cumulate data into the buffer until you get a return value of `0` (meaning the client shut down the socket). `read(sockfd, &recvBuff[total], sizeof(Data) - total)` ensures that the incomming data is properly appended at the right position in the buffer.